# dynamic sql in stored procedure unable to fetch the required result

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

If no parameter is passed to the stored procedure, it should return all the result.

If I pass any one parameter then value should display as per the parameter

```
alter proc SearchEmployee --'','','',''
    @Name varchar(50)=null,
    @Age int=null,
    @Gender varchar(50)=null,
    @Email varchar(50)=null
as
begin

    declare @sql varchar(max), @sqlwhere varchar(max)
    set @sqlwhere = ''; 

    set @sql = 'select * from employee' 

   if ((@Name is not null) and @Name <> '')
   begin
      set @sqlwhere=' Name='+ @Name 
   end
   else if ((@Age is not null) and @Age <> '')
   begin
      set @sqlwhere='and Age='+ cast(@Age as varchar(50)) 
   end
   else if ((@Email is not null) and @Email <> '')
   begin
      set @sqlwhere=' and email='+ @Email
   end
   else if ((@Gender is not null) and @Gender <> '')
   begin
       set @sqlwhere=' and Gender='+ @Gender
   end

   if (@sqlwhere <> '')
   begin
       set @sql = @sql + ' where ' + @sqlwhere;
   end
   else
   begin
        set @sql = @sql;
   end

   print @sql
   exec (@sql) 
end
```

`employee` table

```
Name    Age Gender  email
anurag  24  Male    anu@gmail.com
abhi    22  Male    abhi@gmail.com
ruchi   23  Female  ruchi@gmail.com
siba    24  Male    siba@gmail.com
mukua   24  Male    mukua@gmail.com
prachi  24  Female  prachi@gmail.com
preeti  24  Female  preeti@gmail.com
```

Executing

```
SearchEmployee '','','',''
```

gives me all the results.

But executing the below gives error

```
SearchEmployee 'anurag','','',''`

select * from employee where  Name=anurag
```

Error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'anurag'.

Kindly help me modify the query. And where i am doing wrong ?

Comment: This `select * from employee where  Name=anurag` is trying to find rows where the `Name` column matches the value of the `anurag` column - but there is **no** `anurag` column! You need to put your string values into **single quotes!** - `select * from employee where  Name='anurag'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot about wrapping varchar/nvarchar values with single quotes.
Also if you'll not provide @Name your dynamic query will have e.g. `where and Age = ...` part, i.e. will have unwanted `and` before first filter condition.
Even more, in your implementation there can be only one filter condition (zero or one) because of `if else if` chain. But it seems you want use all passing (i.e. not null) parameters.

By the way, there's no need to use dynamic query. For example you can use this query:

```
select 
    * 
from employee
where
    Name = isnull(@Name, Name)
    and Age = isnull(@Age, Age)
    and email = isnull(@Email, email)
    and Gender = isnull(@Gender, Gender)
```

or

```
select 
    * 
from employee
where
    (@Name is null or Name = @Name)
    and (@Age is null or Age = @Age)
    and (@Email is null or email = @Email)
    and (@Gender is null or Gender = @Gender)
```

**UPD**. Answer to question in comments. Yes, it can be done. And again by isnull (or coalesce) function:

```
-- remove set @sqlwhere = '' in top of the query so @sqlwhere 
-- will be null - it's usefull. 
-- also change if (@sqlwhere <> '') to if (@sqlwhere is not null)

set @sqlwhere = isnull(@sqlwhere + ' and ', '') 
                + ' Age = ''' + cast(@Age as varchar(50)) + ''' ';

-- as you see, I also added single quotes wrapping for @Age value
```

`isnull` has simple logic - if first parameter `is not null` then return it else return second parameter. Also there's a rule in sql that if `null` value appears in arithmetic operation or in string concatenation (our case) then all result will be `null`. So if `@sqlwhere is null` then `@sqlwhere + ' and '` also will be `null`. It means if there's no conditions in `@sqlwhere` then there's no need in `and` word.
Hope it's clear :)

Comment: Superb explanation.. I tried both. And both are working fine.

Comment: But as you said  "Also if you'll not provide @Name your dynamic query will have e.g. where and Age = ... part, i.e. will have unwanted and before first filter condition." . so can it be handled in dynamic query ? Is there any way you can do the same in dynamic query ?

Comment: You are simply awesome.  That is superb explanation again dude. As you said i tried and its working perfectly fine in dynamic sql too...great :)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to debug this type of Dynamic SQL is to simply remove the `exec (@sql)` and just print the SQL Statement. You can then use that statement to work with the query until its right and then make the adjustments in the code based on the changes you made.

In this case you would find that you are missing apostrophes around the parameter. Try something like this:

```
set @sqlwhere=' Name='+ '''' + @Name + ''''
```

Do that for any parameter that is passing in text

Comment: Yaa its working. But i have one question over here. Why 4 quotes is required. I am little confused over here.. Kindly explain me.. it will be helpful for me...

Comment: Is it like  '''' + @Name + ''''   . first quote is start of first string. Then the next two quotes is single quote.Then close the string. So this makes  '''.  Then +@Name+. Then second string starts. Then next two quotes make a single quote. Then the last quote is the end of the second string. Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: Basically in order to get a ' to show up in dynamic sql you have to show it as ''''. The reason for this is that a single ' would never show up because it refers to the start and end of a string. By using 4.. the first 2 say its a string and the middle 2 cancel each other out and become a single '. I know its confusing. I always just learned it as use 4 apostrophes for 1.